# No se muestran en el navegador los cambios que realizo a mi aplicación Symfony hasta que limpio la cache de prod

Tags: php, apache, symfony2, permisos

Estoy trabajando de forma local en una aplicación en Symfony 2.7.5. La app esta montada en otro servidor Linux pero realizo cambios localmente y luego los subo a mano al servidor.

Trabajo en Windows localmente con:
Wamp Server 2.5,
Apache 2.4.9,
PHP 5.5.12.

**Mi problema es:**

Cuando realizo algún cambio en el código de mi aplicación y la ejecuto en mi localhost se muestran los cambios correctamente. Pero cuando subo estos cambios al servidor Linux (el cual tiene Apache y LAMP) y luego ejecuto la app en mi navegador, no se visualizan los cambios hasta que borro la cache de prod en el servidor. Tengo que hacer esto cada vez que subo un cambio para que se visualice.

**Mis preguntas son:**

¿Por que no me ocurre lo mismo que cuando ejecuto en mi localhost la app que tengo local?**:** que se me muestran los cambios automáticamente en el navegador sin necesidad de borrar la cache?

¿Existe alguna forma de no tener que limpiar la cache cada vez que subo algun cambio a dicho servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony tiene dos entornos, el de producción (prod) y el de desarrollo (dev), normalmente cuando desarrollas para poder visualizar los cambios se utiliza el modo de desarrollo, este se utiliza poniendo al final del dominio app_dev.php te quedaría algo así: http://cupon.local/app_dev.php, de esta forma cada vez que hagas un cambio se visualizara sin necesidad limpiar la cache, por otro lado si utilizas el entorno de producción que es sin poner el app_dev.php (http://cupon.local) o en alguna ocasiones solo poniendo al final del dominio app.php, siempre vas a tener que limpiar la cache para poder visualizar los nuevos cambios. Es muy probable que cuando subas tus cambios a la otra PC con Linux estés visualizando el sitio mediante el modo de producción y es por eso que debes borrar siempre la calle de prod.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió. Al menos ya se que tengo que seguirlo haciendolo de esa forma, no hay otra. Si me pudiera decir el por qué siempre hay que hacerlo de esa forma para entender mejor, se lo agradecería. Y sí, visualizo el sitio a través del entorno de producción.

Comment: Bueno esto de los entornos de producción y de desarrollo son cosas propias del framework y normalmente en los servidores en donde se despliegan las aplicaciones siempre se debe ejecutar el modo de producción ya que es mucho más rápido y esta optimizado para esta función, por otro lado el entorno de desarrollo es un poco más lento y muestra mucha información sobre el desarrollo de una aplicación que no le es de interés a los usuarios a los que está dedicada la aplicación.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero lo que quisiera saber es por qué tengo que limpiar la cache del servidor cada vez que subo una actualización para poder acceder a la app con sus nuevos cambios desde otra PC?. Sin embargo localmente no sucede esto, teniendo el proyecto en mi PC solo con dar F5 al navegador visualizo lo nuevo de manera local, sin necesidad de limpiar cache cada vez que haya un mínimo cambio. Gracias, saludos. @DaymerRodriguezFillad